# Set multiple system properties Java command line

Tags: java, command-line, system-properties

Is there an easier way to specify multiple System Properties on the command line to a Java program rather than having multiple -D statements?

Trying to avoid this:

```
 java -jar -DNAME="myName" -DVERSION="1.0" -DLOCATION="home" program.jar
```

I thought I had seen an example of someone using one `-D` and some quoted string after that, but I can't find the example again.

Comment: Starting in Java 9, you can put some or all of those options (e.g., `-DNAME="myName" -DVERSION="1.0" -DLOCATION="home" -jar program.jar`) into a plain text file, and then run the java launcher with the "argument files" syntax, e.g.,  `java @that_plain_text_file`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Answer is NO. You might have seen an example where somebody would have set something like :

`-DArguments=a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=cow`

Then the application would parse value of `Arguments` property string to get individual values.
In your `main` you can get the key values as(Assuming input format is guaranteed):

```
String line = System.getProperty("Arguments");
if(line != null) {
  String str[] = line.split(",");
    for(int i=1;i<str.length;i++){
        String arr[] = str[i].split("=");
        System.out.println("Key = " + arr[0]);
        System.out.println("Value = " +  arr[1]);
    }
}
```

Also, the `-D` should be before the main class or the `jar` file in the java command line. Example : `java  -DArguments=a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=cow MainClass`

Comment: `Also, the -D should be before the main class or the jar file`    Thanks! You save me.

Comment: Arguments can come after the -jar if you use --key=value instead of -Dkey-value.

Answer (score 23):

There's nothing on the [Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) that mentions about anything like that.

Here's a quote:

> -Dproperty=value
>       Set a system property value. If value is a string that
>   contains spaces, you must enclose the string in double quotes:
>
> java -Dfoo="some string" SomeClass

Comment: What class does `SomeClass` is referring to? I'm trying to set this property to read a `.properties` file, using Spring, Struts and Tomcat 8.5, that's the only part of the command that's still unclear to me

Comment: @Frakcool `SomeClass` would be the class with the main method that you are trying to run. Typically it would have a package declaration and you should use the fully qualified class name to run it.

Comment: Oh I get it, it was what I was thinking, however in a web application there's no `main` method, so, I think it's done in the tomcat's properties, am I right?

Comment: @Frakcool there are a number of ways to set system properties. This question was about setting them from the command line. You can also look into setting the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable with the required system properties

Comment: Thank you :) I appreciate your help

Answer (score 17):

Instead of passing the properties as an argument, you may use a .properties for storing them.

Comment: +1: You can also load them into the system properties with `System.getProperties().load(new FileInputStream("my.properties"))` However having your own Properties is likely to be a better approach.

Answer (score 9):

You may be able to use the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable to set options. It worked for me with Rasbian. See [Environment Variables and System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/troubleshoot/environment-variables-and-system-properties.htm#JSTGD610) which has this to say:

> In many environments, the command line is not readily accessible to
>   start the application with the necessary command-line options.
>
> This often happens with applications that use embedded VMs (meaning
>   they use the Java Native Interface (JNI) Invocation API to start the
>   VM), or where the startup is deeply nested in scripts. In these
>   environments the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable can be useful
>   to augment a command line.
>
> When this environment variable is set, the JNI_CreateJavaVM function
>   (in the JNI Invocation API), the JNI_CreateJavaVM function adds the
>   value of the environment variable to the options supplied in its
>   JavaVMInitArgs argument.

However this environment variable use may be disabled for security reasons.

> In some cases, this option is disabled for security reasons. For
>   example, on the Oracle Solaris operating system, this option is
>   disabled when the effective user or group ID differs from the real ID.

See this example showing the difference between specifying on the command line versus using the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable.

[image: screenshot showing use of JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable]

Answer (score 0):

If the required properties need to set in system then there is no option than -D
But if you need those properties while bootstrapping an application then loading properties through the properties files is a best option. It will not require to change build for a single property.

Comment: How is using the `-D` approach require a new build for a single property?