# How to use a logging.properties file from disk as a java.util.logging.properties file

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I have a basic cmd program that calls a jar which has an Install class with the main method.
The Install class uses a java.util.logging.config.file from its resources folder.

```
private static void setupLogging() {
    if (System.getProperty("java.util.logging.config.file") == null) {
        final InputStream inputStream = Install.class.getResourceAsStream("/logging.properties");
        try {
            LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(inputStream);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().severe("Could not load default logging.properties file");
            Logger.getAnonymousLogger().severe(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This install program belongs to a different project and I shouldn't change it. But I want to use a seperate logging.properties file from my disk (preferably from the same folder where I have the cmd program). How do I force this install program to use my logging.properties file instead of it's default one from the resources folder? Is there a way I can force this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
String yourFilePath = "./yourLogProperties.properties";
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(new FileInputStream(yourFilePath);
```

Properties will be loaded from a file stored in the same folder which your app is executed.

**Update:**

I was searching a little bit how to pass properties thru command line and there's a pretty good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351533/set-multiple-system-properties-java-command-line). So, in your case you'll need something like this:

```
java -jar -Djava.util.logging.config.file="./yourLogProperties.properties" YourApp.jar
```

Also you can test if it works making a simple test:

```
public class Tests {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.util.logging.config.file"));
    }    
}
```

Running this from command line you should get the answer `./yourLogProperties.properties`

Comment: Thanks for the input. But the problem here is that I still have to modify the Install class for this. I want to be able to specify the properties file thru command line, is that possible?

Comment: You're wellcome. In that case, you should take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351533/set-multiple-system-properties-java-command-line). You'll need something like `java -jar -Djava.util.logging.config.file="./yourLogProperties.properties"`
I didn't make any test so I can't be shure if it will work. Try and let us know if so!

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to work.For some reason I was thinking that I should force the java.util.logging File to be a system property.