# How do I get to $ prompt in Java (to change the settings)

Tags: java, windows-8, jvm

I need java to use a socks5 proxy.
I found the instructions.
How do I get to the $ prompt to enter them?
Google completely fails at this.

```
$ System.getProperties().put( "proxySet", "true" );
$ System.getProperties().put( "socksProxyHost", "127.0.0.1" );
$ System.getProperties().put( "socksProxyPort", "1234" );
```

Thanks

Comment: You know you can run this without a prompt, right ? Or pass these as arguments to your JVM when you launch it

Comment: How do I launch the JVM? (What exactly do I type in the Windows command prompt.)

Comment: I just want to make Java use a proxy server, regardless of the browsers settings.  I'm launching a java app that you start with a URL.  The app runs it its own window.

Comment: How do you run this thing ?

Comment: I found this, which is related to what you're asking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351533/set-multiple-system-properties-java-command-line

Comment: The comment to the 2nd answer there (9 upvotes) is what I want - but again - how do I get to the $ prompt?