# Routing java intelij traffic through fiddler

Tags: java, https, proxy, fiddler

I am attempting to view https requests in Fiddler made by a program in inteliJ. 
I have been attempting to use the different methods that are posted on the internet. By the way, this is for one-off testing.

These include: 
    - Programmatically
    - This works, but its not scaleable, and we have to add extra code to ignore ssl certificates. I do not want to pursue this path.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");
```

- Exporting Fiddler cert

  - This is the most common thing I am seeing, and I think this is the route that I want to go.
  - Only issue is that once I use keytool and make sure intelij is seeing it (at least I think I am, I am not sure how to confirm), the tests that I am running fail. They ping another port on the server computer, but as soon as they send a request, they fail.

I am not looking to change the proxy service. Right now fiddler is what I need to use. 
I also do not want to do this programattically. I have that working, but its not the solution that I want.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why don't you parameterize that code so that it gets called with the right thing when you need it?  Wrap it in another method and pass it the IP and port.  That cuts your code burden by 75 percent.  If you had a configuration file, you could just edit that and loop through it.

Comment: I should clarify, this is for one-off testing.
Also, doing it through the code directly is not an option.

Comment: [System properties can be set via java command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7351533/150978). You can also you can [specify a different trust store](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29585_01/PlatformServices.61x/security/src/csec_ssl_jsp_start_server.html) (create a JKS file that contains the Fiddler root cert). Therefore no code changes are needed.